# Emacs org-mode sparse trees: combine search criteria

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to explore my org file using sparse trees.

I'm having trouble combining positive and negative conditions with tags with special characters. Here's some searches I've tried (with C-u C-c / m):

```
{-"@vigo"&{SCHEDULED={.}|DEADLINE={.}|TODO="NEXT"|TODO="WAITING"|focus|PRIORITY={.}}}/!

-@vigo&{SCHEDULED={.}|DEADLINE={.}|TODO="NEXT"|TODO="WAITING"|focus|PRIORITY={.}}/!
```

What I'm trying to express is: any headlines without the tag @vigo, which are scheduled, have a deadline, have todo keywords NEXT or WAITING, have the tag focus OR have a priority.

When I use any of the search queries above, entries with the tag @vigo are highlighted. Why?

Comment: If you don't get a response in a reasonable period of time, have a moderator move this question over to emacs.stackexchange.com, or delete and repost it over there -- there is a regular forum participant that eats search criteria for breakfast.

Answer (score 1):

The manual states that "Parentheses are not implemented": http://orgmode.org/org.html#Matching-tags-and-properties, so you have to distribute the -@vigo across all the ORs:

```
-@vigo&SCHEDULED={.}|-@vigo&DEADLINE={.}|...
```

Untested.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an option when I have far too many conditions. This query language is very limited :(